# system.invalidcastexception: 'unable to cast object of type 'system.linq.enumerablequery

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

**Issue is that whenever i try to get user data by id nd not including all the fields from database
asp.net core 3.1 web api**
**My get user class**

```
public class Getuser
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

**My Userinfo class**

```
public partial class Userinfo
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**My Interface method**

```
IQueryable<Userinfo> GetUserId(int id);
```

**My Reprository code**

```
public IQueryable<Userinfo> GetUserId(int id)
    {
        return (IQueryable<Userinfo>)_context.Userinfo.ToList().Select(
            b => new Getuser
            {
                UserId = b.UserId,
                FirstName = b.FirstName,
                LastName = b.LastName
            }).AsQueryable();
    }
```

**calling method to my api controller**

```
public IActionResult GetUser(int id)
    {
        var user = _userReprository.GetUserId(id);
        if (user == null)
            return NotFound();
        else
            return Ok(user);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to acheive... You are seemingly overcomplicating things with `IQueryable`. Why not just return the first or default user

```
public Getuser GetUserById(int id)
{
    return _context.Userinfo.Where(x => x.Id == id)
        .Select(b => new Getuser
           {
               UserId = b.UserId,
               FirstName = b.FirstName,
               LastName = b.LastName
           }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: return type should be `Getuser` then

Comment: @TheGeneral then it displays all the users registered in db with specific fields that i want Userid,Firstname,Lastname  in postman as result i want only specific id user details `[
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "firstName": "text",
        "lastName": "text"
    },
    {
        "userId": 2,
        "firstName": "text",
        "lastName": "text"
    },
    {
        "userId": 3,
        "firstName": "text",
        "lastName": "text"
    }


]`

Comment: @YashShah check again, it only returns 1 user, take special note of the `Where` clause, and `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: @TheGeneral solved `public Getuser GetId(int id)
        {
            return _context.Userinfo.Where(x => x.UserId == id).Select(z => new Getuser
            {
                UserId = z.UserId,
                FirstName = z.FirstName,
                LastName = z.LastName
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }`